# Maven incorrectly advising newer dependency version (3.0.5.RELEASE to 2.5.6, spring)

Tags: maven-2

I just ran

```
mvn versions:display-dependency-updates
```

on my project to check for latest version numbers. Here is some of the output:

```
[INFO] The following dependencies in Dependencies have newer versions:
[INFO]   javax.mail:mail ......................................... 1.4 -> 1.4.4
[INFO]   javax.servlet:servlet-api ................................. 2.4 -> 2.5
[INFO]   junit:junit ............................................. 4.4 -> 4.8.2
[INFO]   org.springframework:spring-context-support .... 3.0.5.RELEASE -> 2.5.6
[INFO]   org.springframework:spring-core ............... 3.0.5.RELEASE -> 2.5.6
[INFO]   org.springframework:spring-webmvc ............. 3.0.5.RELEASE -> 2.5.6
```

Why would Maven decide that 2.5.6 is a newer version than 3.0.5.RELEASE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cause The spring people decided not to follow the [Maven Versioning Schemata](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/version-rules.html).

Comment: I see.. So since they did not format their version as "3.0.5-RELEASE" the whole version string is treated as a 'qualifier', and hence *any* other version is superior?